# How to get librosa.display and matplotlib working in jupyter notebook with anaconda 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, librosa

I'm trying to get Librosa working with python.
Originally I had Python 2.7 installed, I wasn't able to get Librosa working with Python 2.7 so I installed Anaconda (which I've never used before) so that I could have a separate environment (to allow my old programs written in 2.7 to continue to work).  I'm trying to use Jupyter notebook which I've also never used before and I finally managed to import Librosa after creating an Anaconda environment with Python 3.6, however I'm not able to import librosa.display

When I googled "importing Librosa.display" apparently I need to install matplotlib first, however importing matplotlib is failing and I'm not sure why.  I think it might be failing due to importing PIL /pillow? however I've never specifically used that module before or had to install it separately when using matplotlib so I'm not sure why it's needed.
I tried reinstalling pillow using PIP install in the anaconda python3.6 environment that I created but it didn't work so now stuck and just wondering if anyone can help me?

for the import code as follows

```
import matplotlib 
import librosa 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import librosa.display
```

The program gets stuck on "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" and the error message I currently have is as follows (prior to reinstalling pillow it didn't work but the message was different):

```
C:\Users\sh\.conda\envs\signalprocess1\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:130: RuntimeWarning: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 8.2.0
Pillow version: 8.1.2
  warnings.warn(str(v), RuntimeWarning)


C:\Users\sh\.conda\envs\signalprocess1\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py in <module>()
 25 
 26 import numpy as np
---> 27 from PIL import Image
 28 from pyparsing import (
 29     Combine, Empty, FollowedBy, Forward, Group, Literal, oneOf, OneOrMore,

C:\Users\sh\.conda\envs\signalprocess1\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
111     if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
112         raise ImportError(
--> 113             "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
114             f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
115             f"Pillow version: {__version__}"

ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 8.2.0
Pillow version: 8.1.2
```

Any help would be great.  I don't need to use Jupyter I'm perfectly happy using IDLE if IDLE will work with Librosa and matplotlib through Python 3.6.  All I want to do is get Librosa and Matplotlib working so I can analyse signals! I guess if I spend another couple of days on it I'll work it out eventually but it's very annoying spending all this time just trying to get the packages working before I even get to the signal analysis.

thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.....
however in the end I got librosa working with anaconda python 3.8 and jupyter on Windows 10 (64) as follows...

Uninstalled anaconda (possibly it wasn't necessary to uninstall it - not sure)

Uninstalled jupyter the best I could (still seemed to be some remnants associated with arcpy)

Installed miniconda the python 3.8 version

Created a new (separate) Conda environment which also used python 3.8

This was done by opening the Conda command prompt then typing......

```
conda create --name signalpro38 python=3.8
```

(note that signalpro38 is the name I gave the new environment)

activated the new environment by typing:

```
conda activate signalpro38
```

Installed:

- matplotlib,
- scipy,
- numba,
- numpy

then

- jupyter

into the new environment (signalpro38)
by typing

```
conda install matplotlib 
conda install scipy
```

etc.

Added the new anaconda environment to jupyter by following the instructions here:

https://medium.com/@nrk25693/how-to-add-your-conda-environment-to-your-jupyter-notebook-in-just-4-steps-abeab8b8d084

opened jupyter and created a new notebook (making sure to choose the name of the new environment signalpro38)

typed code into the new notebook, saved and ran it, to check that the commands

```
import matplotlib
```

and

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

were working ok in jupyter

Closed jupyter and went back to the Conda command prompt  (the signalpro38 environment that I had created was still activated)
then installed librosa using

```
pip install librosa
```

(note that "conda install librosa" didn't find librosa, however I imagine there is a way to install librosa using conda also)

opened jupyter again and the previously saved notebook file and added

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
```

all seems to be working well now! :)

Hopefully this will help someone else! most likely it will help me when I need to do this again one day! :p

Comment: wow, I totally forgot I went through all this, sure I will have to come back and look at it again sometime haha